# How can I solve this exercise on python?

Tags: python

> Use of cheques as a payment method is still practiced by some companies and/or vendors. The amount being paid normally appears on a cheque twice, with one occurrence written using digits, and the other occurrence written using English words. Repeating the amount in two different forms makes it much more difficult to modify the amount on the cheque before depositing it. In this exercise, your task is to write a function number_to_text(value)-> str that takes a numerical value as input that is less then 1000000 accurate up to two decimal places (you can assume the value will be non-negative) and that returns a string containing the English words for that number.

This is what I got:

```
def number_to_text(value):
    # Define the words for numbers from 0 to 19
    words = {
        0: 'Zero', 1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five',
        6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 10: 'Ten',
        11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen',
        15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen',
        19: 'Nineteen'
    }
    # Define the words for tens multiples
    tens_words = {
        20: 'Twenty', 30: 'Thirty', 40: 'Forty', 50: 'Fifty',
        60: 'Sixty', 70: 'Seventy', 80: 'Eighty', 90: 'Ninety'
    }
    # Special case for zero
    if value == 0:
        return words[0]

    # Split the value into dollars and cents
    dollars = int(value)
    cents = int((value - dollars) * 100)
    dollars_text = ""
    if dollars > 0:
        thousands = dollars // 1000
        hundreds = dollars % 1000 // 100
        tens = dollars % 100 // 10
        ones = dollars % 10
        if thousands > 0:
            dollars_text += words[thousands] + "Thousand"
        if hundreds > 0:
            dollars_text += words[hundreds] + "Hundred"
        if tens > 1:
            dollars_text += tens_words[tens * 10] + " "
            if ones <= 10:
                dollars_text += words[ones] + " "
        elif tens == 1:
            dollars_text += words[tens * 10 + ones] + " "
        elif ones > 0:
            dollars_text += words[ones] + " "
        dollars_text = dollars_text.strip()

    cents_text = ""
    if cents > 0:
        cents_text = str(cents) + "/100"

    if dollars_text and cents_text:
        return dollars_text + " and " + cents_text
    if dollars_text:
        return dollars_text
    if cents_text:
        return cents_text
    else:
        return "Zero"

    print(number_to_text(10))  
    print(number_to_text(1.20))  
    print(number_to_text(999))  
    print(number_to_text(102))  
    print(number_to_text(0.23))  
    print(number_to_text(999999))
```

But I get an error:

```
Nine Hundred Ninety Nine
One Hundred Two
23/100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\UHasselt\Msc Stat&DS Year1\Programing with Python_Code\Assignment 5.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(number_to_text(999999))  # Output: Nine Hundred Ninety Nine Thousand Nine Hundred Ninety Nine
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\UHasselt\Msc Stat&DS Year1\Programing with Python_Code\Assignment 5.py", line 31, in number_to_text
    dollars_text += words[thousands] + " Thousand "
                    ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 999
PS C:\Users\DELL E5580\.vscode> & "C:/Users/DELL E5580/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe" "d:/UHasselt/Msc Stat&DS Year1/Programing with Python_Code/Assignment 5.py"  
Ten
One and 19/100
Nine Hundred Ninety Nine
One Hundred Two
23/100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\UHasselt\Msc Stat&DS Year1\Programing with Python_Code\Assignment 5.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(number_to_text(999999))  # Output: Nine Hundred Ninety Nine Thousand Nine Hundred Ninety Nine
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\UHasselt\Msc Stat&DS Year1\Programing with Python_Code\Assignment 5.py", line 31, in number_to_text
    dollars_text += words[thousands] + " Thousand "
                    ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 999
PS C:\Users\DELL E5580\.vscode>
```

These were the expected outputs:

```
Output 1
'Ten'
Output 2
'One and 20/100'
Output 3
'Nine Hundred Ninety Nine' 
Output 4
'One Hundred Two' 
Output 5
'23/100'
Output 6
'Nine Hundred Ninety Nine Thousand Nine Hundred Ninety Nine'
```

Comment: Obviously your code only accounts for numbers up to "thousands" but you need up to "hundred thousands".

Comment: You're trying to do a lookup in your dictionary with an nonexistent key of 999. That's why you get the error: 
"KeyError: 999". You need to reexamine how that key is computed in your code.

Answer (score 1):

given the code above, the middle part with the if statements should look like this:

```py
        if thousands > 0:
            dollars_text += str(thousands) + " Thousand "
        if hundreds > 0:
            dollars_text += str(hundreds) + " Hundred "
        if tens > 1:
            dollars_text += str(tens) + " Tens "
            if ones <= 10:
                dollars_text += str(ones) + " ones "
```

which gives this:

```
999Thousand 9Hundred 9Tens 9ones
```

You could then work on improving this working version to something a bit more desirable.

Also, if you are looking up a dict that might not contain the `key` that you seek then it is better to use the `get()` method to avoid `KeyError` errors.

Answer (score 0):

I added a helper function to reuse some code. Basically I turn the thousands and the hundreds into text separately and then concatenate them:

```py
words = {
    0: 'Zero', 1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five',
    6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 10: 'Ten',
    11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen',
    15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen',
    19: 'Nineteen'
}
# Define the words for tens multiples
tens_words = {
    20: 'Twenty', 30: 'Thirty', 40: 'Forty', 50: 'Fifty',
    60: 'Sixty', 70: 'Seventy', 80: 'Eighty', 90: 'Ninety'
}  

def number_to_text(value):
    # Special case for zero
    if value == 0:
        return words[0]

    # Split the value into dollars and cents
    dollars = round(value)
    cents = round((value - float(dollars)) * 100)
    dollars_text = ""
    if dollars > 0:
        if len(str(dollars)) > 3:
            first_part = int(str(dollars)[:-3])
            second_part = int(str(dollars)[-3:])
            thousands_text = hundreds_to_text(first_part) + "Thousand "
            hundreds_text = hundreds_to_text(second_part)
            dollars_text = thousands_text + hundreds_text
        else:
            dollars_text = hundreds_to_text(dollars)

    cents_text = ""
    if cents > 0:
        cents_text = str(cents) + "/100"

    if dollars_text and cents_text:
        return dollars_text + "and " + cents_text
    if dollars_text:
        return dollars_text
    if cents_text:
        return cents_text
    else:
        return "Zero"

        
def hundreds_to_text(number):
    dollars_text = ""
    hundreds = number % 1000 // 100
    tens = number % 100 // 10
    ones = number % 10
    if hundreds > 0:
        dollars_text += words[hundreds] + " Hundred "
    if tens > 1:
        dollars_text += tens_words[tens * 10] + " "
        if ones <= 10:
            dollars_text += words[ones] + " "
    elif tens == 1:
        dollars_text += words[tens * 10 + ones] + " "
    elif ones > 0:
        dollars_text += words[ones] + " "
    dollars_text = dollars_text
    return dollars_text

print(number_to_text(10)+ '\n')  
print(number_to_text(1.20)+ '\n')  
print(number_to_text(999)+ '\n')  
print(number_to_text(102)+ '\n')  
print(number_to_text(0.23)+ '\n')  
print(number_to_text(999999)+ '\n')
```

Output:

```
Ten 

One and 20/100

Nine Hundred Ninety Nine 

One Hundred Two 

23/100

Nine Hundred Ninety Nine Thousand Nine Hundred Ninety Nine
```

I also fixed the rounding error by using `round()`and `float()` instead of just casting to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into groups of three. Have the function handle 3 digits then tack on "million", "thousand", "".

```
import random

# Convert any 3 digit number to string
def three_digits_to_text(value, c):
  words = {
        0: 'Zero', 1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five',
        6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 10: 'Ten',
        11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen',
        15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen',
        19: 'Nineteen',
        20: 'Twenty', 30: 'Thirty', 40: 'Forty', 50: 'Fifty',
        60: 'Sixty', 70: 'Seventy', 80: 'Eighty', 90: 'Ninety'
  }
  
  # Get the individual digits. Ex: 123 -> [1,2,3] and 12 -> [0, 1, 2]
  parts = []
  while value:
    digit = value % 10
    value //= 10
    parts.insert(0, digit)
  while len(parts) < 3: parts.insert(0, 0)

  # Hundreds
  result = "" if parts[0] == 0 else f"{words[parts[0]]} Hundred "
  # Tens and ones
  if parts[1] != 0:
    tens = int(f"{parts[1]}{parts[2]}")
    if tens in words:
      result += words[tens]
    else:
      result += f"{words[parts[1] * 10]} {words[parts[2]]}"
  else:
    result += words[parts[2]]

  return f"{result} {c}"

def number_to_text(value):
  dollars,cents = str(value).split('.')
  if len(cents) == 1: cents += '0'
  
  u = ["", "", "Thousand", "Million"]
  # Split number to list. Ex: 1234 -> [1, 234]
  groups = [int(i) for i in f"{int(dollars):,}".split(',')]
  # i is the index into the u array
  i = len(groups)
  result = []
  for g in groups:
    result.append(three_digits_to_text(g, u[i]))
    i -= 1

  cents = three_digits_to_text(int(cents), "Cents")
  
  return f"{', '.join(result)}Dollars and {cents}"

# Test
for _ in range(20):
  dollars = random.randrange(0, 1000000)
  cents = random.randrange(0, 99)
  test = dollars + (cents / 100)
  print(f"{test} --> {number_to_text(test)}")
```

Output:

```
574891.92 --> Five Hundred Seventy Four Thousand, Eight Hundred Ninety One Dollars and Ninety Two Cents
474433.44 --> Four Hundred Seventy Four Thousand, Four Hundred Thirty Three Dollars and Forty Four Cents
860648.59 --> Eight Hundred Sixty Thousand, Six Hundred Forty Eight Dollars and Fifty Nine Cents
261194.96 --> Two Hundred Sixty One Thousand, One Hundred Ninety Four Dollars and Ninety Six Cents
892464.72 --> Eight Hundred Ninety Two Thousand, Four Hundred Sixty Four Dollars and Seventy Two Cents
57049.37 --> Fifty Seven Thousand, Forty Nine Dollars and Thirty Seven Cents
766264.8 --> Seven Hundred Sixty Six Thousand, Two Hundred Sixty Four Dollars and Eighty Cents
630303.63 --> Six Hundred Thirty Thousand, Three Hundred Three Dollars and Sixty Three Cents
993215.33 --> Nine Hundred Ninety Three Thousand, Two Hundred Fifteen Dollars and Thirty Three Cents
143741.81 --> One Hundred Forty Three Thousand, Seven Hundred Forty One Dollars and Eighty One Cents
123817.5 --> One Hundred Twenty Three Thousand, Eight Hundred Seventeen Dollars and Fifty Cents
624711.02 --> Six Hundred Twenty Four Thousand, Seven Hundred Eleven Dollars and Two Cents
917559.87 --> Nine Hundred Seventeen Thousand, Five Hundred Fifty Nine Dollars and Eighty Seven Cents
214254.13 --> Two Hundred Fourteen Thousand, Two Hundred Fifty Four Dollars and Thirteen Cents
476757.62 --> Four Hundred Seventy Six Thousand, Seven Hundred Fifty Seven Dollars and Sixty Two Cents
835674.96 --> Eight Hundred Thirty Five Thousand, Six Hundred Seventy Four Dollars and Ninety Six Cents
586861.05 --> Five Hundred Eighty Six Thousand, Eight Hundred Sixty One Dollars and Five Cents
10750.68 --> Ten Thousand, Seven Hundred Fifty Dollars and Sixty Eight Cents
59989.0 --> Fifty Nine Thousand, Nine Hundred Eighty Nine Dollars and Zero Cents
145960.49 --> One Hundred Forty Five Thousand, Nine Hundred Sixty Dollars and Forty Nine Cents
```